my @RequestBody annotation is not parsing my object
I am having a problem, where I send a request with a Json body, and the parser is not changing that Json into the desired Java object, it is returning that object with all the parameters null:
This is the request from postman:
POST http://localhost:8084/api/user/user

body: {
    "name": "Santiago",
    "email": "yes",
    "number": "4",
    "password": "rftgybn",
    "date_of_birth": "2024-11-06T12:30:00Z",
    "location": "Medellin"
}



This is the request shown by my springboot filter I made (I made it so I could verify the request is correct, the problem existed before making that filter):
POST "/api/user/user", parameters={}

Request Body: {
  "name": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "number": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "date_of_birth": "2024-11-07T11:27:15.086Z",
  "location": "string"
}

This is my DTO object:
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserRegisterRequestDTO {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty("number")
    private String number;
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String password;
    @JsonProperty("date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    @JsonProperty("location")
    private String location;
}

This is my controller method that is being invoked:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class UserControllerImplementation implements UserController {
    @Override
    @PostMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<UserBasicDTO> createUser(@RequestBody UserRegisterRequestDTO user) {
        System.out.println("\n\nCreating user");
        System.out.println(user);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(userService.createUser(user));
    }
}

Those System.out.println() are printing the following:
Creating user
UserRegisterRequestDTO(name=null, email=null, number=null, password=null, dateOfBirth=null, location=null)

I have been trying for a day now, and I do not know what else to do. Please help, and thanks a lot!

You missed the @Setter annotation.

on class UserRegisterRequestDTO add "@Setter" or just replace all annotations with "@Data"

It's working for me with the same code you have.
Try adding @AllArgsConstructor and @Setter on DTOs.

You only need one of those.

Still not working for me, added both of em, and nothing.
Something weird, is that I just tried to convert it in the filter I mentioned, and It parses it just fine

Turns out, that when adding the @RequestBody annotation, I was importing the annotation from Swagger, not the annotation from Springframework.web.bind.annotation.
In Summary, I was importing the wrong @RequestBody. :(

Try this:
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllargsConstructor
public class UserRegisterRequestDTO {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty("number")
    private String number;
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String password;
    @JsonProperty("date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    @JsonProperty("location")
    private String location;
}

For working objectMapper that deserialization and serialization in java. dto must have default constructor and constructor that all field in dto.

Nothing, still null

when i use your controller and dto that to add @AllargsConstructor code worked correct curl -X POST 'localhost:9797/user' { data } Creating user UserRegisterRequestDTO(name=Santiago, email=yes, number=4, password=rftgybn, dateOfBirth=Wed Nov 06 21:30:00 KST 2024, location=Medellin)

could you add import path?

Are you using the Body parameter in Postman with raw selected and JSON as the type?
If not, try using the following curl command into your terminal:
curl --location 'http://localhost:8084/api/user/user' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "name": "Santiago",
    "email": "yes",
    "number": "4",
    "password": "rftgybn",
    "date_of_birth": "2024-11-06T12:30:00Z",
    "location": "Medellin"
}'


Yes, I have post man in json, and also a Vite front end in json, and still nothing
